# Move button in another CSS file onto index.php?

Tags: php, html, css

Yeah I know my question is probably very confusing but just hear me out. Basically I have a test website with a login system that logs you in with the Steam API. My login button is styled on a separate CSS file than my index.php CSS file. Basically, I can't move the login button onto the top header because they are separate files. Any help would be appreciated.

Website (If You Want To See What I'm Talking About.) http://abyssallogin.hol.es

**EDIT:** (I just want to move the button from where it is now up ontop of the header to the right of the navigation choices.)

**Index.php**

```
<?php
    require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';
?>

<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SteamLoginTest</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    </head>
    <body>
        <? if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) { ?>

            <nav class="navigation">
                <div class="navigation-logo">Website</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Deposit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Withdraw</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Free Coins</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
                <? loginbutton(); ?>
            </nav>
            <span class="login-message">You are not currently logged in.</span>

        <? } else { ?>

            <nav class="navigation">
                <div class="navigation-logo">Website</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Deposit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Withdraw</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Free Coins</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
                <? logoutbutton(); ?>
            </nav>

            <span class="login-message">You are now logged in.</span>
            <? include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); ?>

        <? } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Index.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.navigation > .navigation-logo {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

.navigation > ul {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
    float: left;
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.login-message {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Steamauth.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();

    function logoutbutton() {
        echo "<form id='button' action='' method='get'><button class='btn red' name='logout' type='submit'>Logout</button></form>";
    }

    function loginbutton() {
        echo "<form id='button' action='' method='get'><button class='btn red' name='login' type='submit'>Login</button></form>";
    }

    if (isset($_GET['login'])){
        require 'openid.php';
        try {
            require 'SteamConfig.php';
            $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

            if(!$openid->mode) {
                $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
                header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
            } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
                echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
            } else {
                if($openid->validate()) { 
                    $id = $openid->identity;
                    $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                    preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

                    $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];
                    if (!headers_sent()) {
                        header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location.href="<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>";
                        </script>
                        <noscript>
                            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>" />
                        </noscript>
                        <?php
                        exit;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "User is not logged in.\n";
                }
            }
        } catch(ErrorException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
        require 'SteamConfig.php';
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: '.$steamauth['logoutpage']);
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['update'])){
        unset($_SESSION['steam_uptodate']);
        require 'userInfo.php';
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SteamLoginTest</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/steamauth.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body id="steamauth">

    </body>
</html>
```

**Steamauth.css**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1500px;
}

.btn {
    float: right;
    border: none;
    margin: 20px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
}

.red {
    background-color: rgb(231, 76, 60);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgb(206, 51, 25);
}

.red:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 102, 86);
}
```

Comment: See what happens when you remove `margin-left: 1500px;` from `#button` then remove the `margin-right: 400px;` from `.navigation > ul`

Comment: Also, I don't see where you are closing off `ob_start();` on your `Steamauth.php` page, but if you are doing it to suppress errors (header output before redirect errors), you should probably just figure out a way to fix that script. It not really best practice to suppress errors.

Comment: After viewing your source I see what you mean about two files, you should not be combining those files like that...

Comment: I tried removing both and this is what it currently looks like: http://abyssallogin.hol.es/

Comment: Well, I don't know what you are actually looking for, I assumed you wanted the login to float right? At any rate, you have to fix that double html you have. Cut out the two lines `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/steamauth.css"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">` from `Steamauth.php` and paste them into the `index.php` page, then delete all the html off the `Steamauth.php` page so you just have the PHP remaining

Comment: Instead of keeping login button outside <nav> <ul>, can you not keep it within a <li> in <ul>, and place it at the last position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these css:

```
.navigation > ul
{
    margin-right: 165px;
}
#button
{
    postion: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```